# ssh password less authentication doesn't work

Tags: ssh

sorry for posting common topic again. I read several similar question but I still haven't found why it is not working. So let me describe what I did.
I generated private/public rsa key files on a different machine than client/server are.

Then I created `~/.ssh` dir and copy over private key `id_rsa` on a client side, set appropriate owner and  file permissions. On a server side I created again under the user I want connect to `~/.ssh` put  the public key into authorized keys.

When I tried ssh client to host it still requires password even though that keys were generated as password less.

Did I overlooked something obvious?

I also tried to find on a server side check the ssh log for details why it requires passwd - but /var/log/auth or /var/log/ssh doesn't exist. Isn't it enabled by default or do I need to change config of sshd and restart the service.

I'm using CentOS 6.

To Answer the questions:
~/.ssh on server side:

```
rw-------. hdfs hadoop  authorized_keys

rw-------. hdfs hadoop  config

rw-------. hdfs hadoop  id_rsa.pub
```

cnfig contains:

```
Host *
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

~/.ssh on client side:

```
rw-------. hdfs hadoop authorized_keys

rw-------. hdfs hadoop config - the content is the same

rw-------. hdfs hadoop id_rsa

rw-r--r--. hdfs hadoop known_hosts
```

- this one were probably generated by my attempts

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but did you put the key in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server side? And it is the `id_rsa.pub` you copied on the server, not the `id_rsa`, right?

Comment: Please include the _actual_ exact command you ran and their output. We can't know if you've done it correctly if you don't show what you did.

Comment: Also show the output of `ssh -vvv remotehost`.

Comment: Please share output from `ls -l ~/.ssh`, and `ls -la | grep .ssh`.

Comment: When I do regenerate the key on the client machine than it works. Is the hostname somehow encoded into the key or so?

Comment: What @WarrenYoung said, and see if you can't also temporarily raise the debug level of the sshd process on the server end, find out why it's rejecting the RSA handshake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CentOS 6, there is a [bug that prevents ssh RSA authentication from working](http://bugs.centos.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=4959) as desired if selinux is in Enforcing mode.

You can disable selinux, or you can try the workaround below:

```
restorecon -R -v ~$USER/.ssh
```

Comment: Yea this helps when I do that manually. But I don't know why this doesn't work when I execute that command externally -as via some Config Management tool as puppet. For sure replacing user with correct value

Answer (score 3):

These two lines from the [ssh centos-howto](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH) solved the issue for me:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. Add the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remotehost
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_private_key
```