# passwordless ssh is not working in CentOS 6.4?

Tags: ssh, centos

I am setting up passwordless login from [this link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH) but I can't get it to work.

When I do `ssh localhost` it always asks for a password.

I have also referred to this question: [ssh password less authentication doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/ssh-password-less-authentication-doesnt-work)

```
[impadmin@pearl ~]$ ssh localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 6c:d3:3b:cc:05:7f:10:e8:17:cc:4c:14:be:01:bb:f7.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
impadmin@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
impadmin@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
impadmin@localhost's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

**Update**

```
ls .ssh/ -l
total 16
-rw-------. 1 impadmin impadmin  396 Apr  9 17:04 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 impadmin impadmin 1675 Apr  9 17:03 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 impadmin impadmin  396 Apr  9 17:03 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 impadmin impadmin  391 Apr  9 17:05 known_hosts
```

I am trying to achieve password less login on same machine for user impadmin to install Hadoop.

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -l ~/.ssh` for the account you`re trying with.

Comment: Would you mind explaining us, which kind of »passwordless authentication« you talk about?  Public-key, empty password, …?

Comment: @JennyD please see updated question

Comment: @AndreasWiese I am trying to achieve password less login on same machine for user impadmin to install Hadoop

Comment: Check the permissions on all directories below `.ssh` in the tree - none of them can have write permissions other than for owner/root. Also check that the sshd config allows for `PubkeyAuthentication`. And check the logs (usually /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log) for any information.

Comment: @JennyD getting this in logs  18:36:26 pearl sshd[6279]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/impadmin

Comment: got the answer problem is due to permissions on home directory of impadmin user

Comment: Cool, I'll write it up with an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for public key authentication to work, the SSH daemon needs to be sure that the key in the authorized_keys file can't be tampered with by anyone other than the owner (and root, of course).

This means that the write permissions of the user's `~/.ssh` directory, and all directories leading up to it from `/` must be restricted so that only the owner (and root) can write to them. So if your home directory is `/home/impadmin`, you need to check the following:

- `/home` should be mode `dwrx-rx-rx` and owned by root
- `/home/impadmin` should be owned by `impadmin` and only allow write access by `impadmin` - no write access for group or other. You may choose whether to allow read/execute access for group/other, but if you allow them write access then the public key won't work.
- `/home/impadmin/.ssh` should have permissions `drwx------` and be owned by `impadmin`
- `/home/impadmin/.ssh/id_rsa` should have permissions `-rw-------` and be owned by `impadmin`
- `/home/impadmin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `/home/impadmin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` must be owned by `impadmin` and not have write permission for any other user. They may be readable, but not writable.

If any of the directories or files is writable by another user than impadmin, SSH will consider this a possible break-in and will not allow a login using keys.